# Are there URI schemas for identifying IP addresses and domain names?

Tags: url, dns, ip, uri, rdf

Is there a Unique Resource Identifier (URI) schema which allows to uniquely refer to IP addresses and domain names?

For example "http://8o.232.240.50" or "http://supersite.com" are not refering to IP address or a domain name, rather they are refering to some resource which can be accessed via HTTP protocol and it's HTTP path happens to include this given IP address or domain name. Therefore they are more of Unique Resource Locators (URL) than Unique Resource Identifiers (URI) or Unique Resource Names (URN).

What I am looking for are schemas like "mailto:someemai@something.com" for IP addresses and/or domain names.

Something like "domain:supersite.com" and "ip:80.232.240.50".

I could make up schemes like these for my own use, but I am wondering if there isn't something like this already out there. And if there isn't, why?

Answer (score 1):

[**RFC 4501**: Domain Name System Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4501)

> The Domain Name System (DNS) […] is a widely deployed system
> used, among other things, to translate host names into IP addresses.
> Several protocols use Uniform Resource Identifiers (URIs) to refer to
> data.  By defining a URI scheme for DNS data, the gap between these
> two worlds is bridged.  The DNS URI scheme defined here can be used
> to reference any data stored in the DNS.

From the [examples](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4501#section-4):

- `dns:www.example.org.?clAsS=IN;tYpE=A`
- `dns:www.example.org`
- `dns:simon.example.org?type=CERT`
- `dns://192.168.1.1/ftp.example.org?type=A`
- `dns:world%20wide%20web.example%5c.domain.org?TYPE=TXT`
- `dns://fw.example.org/*.%20%00.example?type=TXT`

According to the [syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4501#section-3), it should be possible to use the `dnsauthority` with an empty `dnsname`. `dnsauthority` takes a `host` as defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2), which says:

> `host        = IP-literal / IPv4address / reg-name`

So it should be possible to use domain names as well as IP addresses (an empty `dnsname` "is to be interpreted as the root itself").

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! First I would like to add to the other answer in that `dns:` is not (as I understand it) identifying *domain names*, instead it *uses* domain names to identify whatever resource might be available through DNS via that name, in the same manner that `tel:` URIs identify resources available through the telephone network represented by telephone numbers, and not the telephone numbers themselves. That is also the reason why there is no `ip:` scheme, since it is too generic to identify anything in the same manner.

That being said, you also request something similar to `mailto:`, but that is in contradiction with the paragraph above ‒ `mailto:` URIs identify (per [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068)) "resources that are reached using Internet mail", such as mailboxes, not e-mail addresses. An e-mail address is an identifier, wrapped in a URI made to identify the resource located through that particular address. If what you wish is something analogous, then `dns:` is probably that, since a *domain name* identifies, by definition, a domain (I suppose a domain is an abstract resource that is described by a DNS record). You can also convert an IP address to a domain name using `in-addr.arpa` and use that as a URI, so `80.232.240.50` would be `dns:50.240.232.80.in-addr.arpa`. Not sure what exactly this would denote, but it is closest to what you request.

If you want to actually identify IP addresses and domain names, as identifiers themselves, there are no URI schemes for that (there is not much necessity for them anyway), but for the purposes of RDF, you may use [uri4uri](https://uri4uri.is4.site/) which provides identifiers for various parts of URIs, including the hostname, such as [`https://w3id.org/uri4uri/host/80.232.240.50`](https://uri4uri.is4.site/host.html/80.232.240.50). The resolver also provides an description of the IP address in RDF, as a bonus.